# would organize it at a place that was safe

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

So when there was a meeting **Joey would organize it at a place that
was safe.**

This part ( Joey  would organize it at a place that **was safe** )
In that type of sentence, Is about past or present?

Comment: It's habitual in the past.

Comment: ***If there was*** (or "subjunctive" ***were***) ***to be a meeting tomorrow**, Joey would organize it at a place that was safe*. Which so far as I'm concerned means exactly the same as *If there **is** to be a meeting tomorrow, Joey **will** organize it at a place that **is** safe*.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is best analyzed as a whole. As Colin says, the overall issue is habitual, starting with 'would organize'. This is saying that, at several times in the past, as a habitual trait, Joey 'would organize'.

We then modify the organize by throwing in the placeholder pronoun 'it' and the adverbial phrase 'at a place that was safe'. The 'was safe' here needs to be in the past, because the whole thing is in the habitual past.

This could have been said as, 'Whenever we have a meeting, Joey organizes it at a place that is safe.' These mean basically the same thing, but the first emphasizes Joey's past action, and the second one the habitual nature. The second one would more easily imply that we might have another meeting, organized by Joey. (In a place that is safe :) )